# Facebook login on headless browser

Tags: facebook, node.js, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, phantomjs

My Facebook app has a function of automating tasks on server side headless browser (like visiting app links).
Now, I use the Facebook SDKs to log user in and access user's news stream to search for links and other information. 
Once the app has found all the links, it is supposed to pass this information in to the headless browser which will then proceed to visit in them for example.

The problem is that these headless browser windows' are not logged in. I would like the headless browser to be temporary logged in as the user launching the tasks from the app.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd assume the headless browser is server-side code. Once the server has the user's access_token and uses it to access Facebook, isn't it essentially accessing on behalf of the user... as though the user was logged in..

Comment: Isn't access_token only for accessing the API? Or does the API has functionality to visit links found from the stream? I can't find one.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home with correct access_token returns the news feed. All links including external links can be extracted from this feed. The headless browser can than proceed to access these links.

Comment: If the action link is an URL for another Facebook app, lets say The Sims Social for example, you can't access the link in the browser without logging in. Even with access token. That's like if you'd get the link in Chrome and try to access the link in Firefox without logging in. You can try it yourself.